# What exactly is "Viewport"?

Tags: puppeteer

I have troubles understanding what exactly "Viewport" is. The [docs](https://puppeteer.github.io/puppeteer/docs/puppeteer.page.viewport) say it defines the "width" and the "height" in a "page". And what exactly was "page", again? I used to think of it as a browser tab, but this is also wrong, see below...

My tests fail because I seem to misunderstand "Viewport":

```
page.setViewport({ width: 640, height: 480 })
expect(window.innerWidth).toBe(640) // FAIL, it's 1366, Puppeteers default
```

From googling around, I know that there are options to launch Puppeteer in another window size. But this is not what I'm looking for, out of two reasons:

1. it still doesn't explain what "Viewport" is
2. I can't "restart" Puppeteer in every single test (I'm testing responsive behavior)

https://puppeteer.github.io/puppeteer/docs/puppeteer.page.viewport

Answer (score 0):

You should expect the `page.evaluate` result of `window.innerWidth`.
Remember that the execution context inside of the page itself is different with puppeteer context.

```
import puppeteer, { Browser, BrowserContext, Page } from 'puppeteer'

const start = async () => {
    const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page: Page = await browser.newPage()
    page.setViewport({ width: 640, height: 480 })
    await page.goto('http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/id43.htm', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    expect(await page.evaluate(() => window.innerWidth)).toBe(640)
    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => window.innerWidth))
    await page.close()
    await browser.close()
}

;(async () => await start())()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with expecting the innerWidth via evaluate().

Comment: @kraftwer1 Please select this answer as the right one,
My pleasure.

Comment: It doesn't answer the threads title question "What exactly is Viewport?".